# Cipher.unwrap() key length Sun - BouncyCastle compatibility

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have some JDK 1.6 code I'm porting to Android, and it's behaving differently.

```
// decode public key
pubk = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(
    new X509EncodedKeySpec(X)
);
// decode symmetric key
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, pubk);
skey = (SecretKey)cipher.unwrap(key1, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
```

`pubk` is 2048-bit RSA key, though in different representations (Sun or OpenSSL).
`key1` is 2048-bit byte array.

**Problem is:** I have different results for `skey`. On Sun JRE it is 128-bit AES key, on Android it is 2048-bit array, **containing following bytes:

[1, -1, -1 ... ,-1, 0, (actual key bytes here)]**

Original wrapping is done the following way:

```
        // generate symmetric key
        kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(128, SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"));
        skey = kgen.generateKey();

        // create Cipher
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);

        // decode private key
        privk = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(
            new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(X)
        );

        // wrap symmetric key
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, privk);
        skey_buffer = cipher.wrap(skey);
```

During wrapping (in Sun JRE) `skey` is 128 bit, resulting `skey_buffer` is 2048 bit

<s>I suppose it has something to do with Sun's restrictions of key length to 128-bit.</s>  Now I suppose it has something to do with padding. But how do I apply such restrictions to BouncyCastle implementation, to get the same unwrapped key output? Sure I can hardcode cutting out that `-1`'s at the beginning of decoded array, but maybe there are some (padding) parameters that can get original 128-bit text?

**Upd:** I was not attentive, and missed the fact unwrapped `skey` was not 256-bit, but 2048-bit. Updated question.

Comment: I currently have no time, so I've just hardcoded array conversion, but I will return to this problem and try to solve it correctly. RSA padding specifications seems promising...

Answer (score 1):

The size of the binary data - the AES key -  is determined during decryption.

The size of the encrypted plaintext data is determined by the PKCS#1 v1.5 unpadding mechanism in the Sun provider (which you get after modular exponentiation with the private key, the first step of decryption). In other words, the Sun provider defaults to `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"`.

However in the Android provider the PKCS#1 v1.5 unpadding is not performed, instead it seems to default to `"RSA/ECB/NoPadding"`. That's why you see all the -1 values in the result; this is part of the padding. This also means that the padding mechanism for signature generation is used instead of the one used for encryption. This is because **you are using the private key instead of the public key** to perform the encryption.

So you should explicitly specify `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` and use the RSA public key for the wrapping (it's no use if everybody can decrypt your AES key, right?). Try and use OAEP encryption instead (that would be `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"` in Java). PCKS#1 padding is vulnerable to certain kinds of attacks.

Comment: Supplied encrypted data is the same; I added a code snipped how it was wrapped. And I inspected a size of `skey` wrongly, corrected that in question. So it's not different keys wrapped, but seems you are right about padding parameters. If only I could understand something about them :)

Comment: Ah, yes, amended answer. Remember: private key for sign and decrypt, public key for verify and encrypt.